# How should we tag questions about Business Economics?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm writing a question about business start-up from an economical approach.

Is a practical and answerable question i think.

How should be tagged?

EDIT:

It would be preferable to wait for public beta? I'm no expert in economics. On the contrary, I am learning on my own and although the question makes perfect sense to me, after reading many questions here in Meta, I am unsure if it is the right time.

Comment: Sounds like *industrial organization* to me. But yeah, don't overthink it.

Answer (score 5):

Post you question with whatever tags you think are appropriate! If people think the question or tags can be improved then they will edit your post accordingly. If people don't think the question belongs in the private beta then they can always vote to close it. Don't take this personally: this is the process by which we, as a community, figure out what shape the site should take.

Answer (score 2):

Just as Ubiquitous says. There´s a practical and a theoretical side to Economics, but ultimately the theory isn´t very useful if it can´t inform us on the practical side. It´s in applying theory to practical questions that it can be most illuminating.